# Porque me sale este error: "Violacion de Segmento" al ejecutar la funcion add?

Tags: c

Implementé las funciones pero no he podido verificar si estan bien, debido a que tengo que ejecutar primero la funcion add pero me sale el error de violacion de segmento, no se si esté usando de manera correcta Malloc:

1 Sistema de Control de Versiones
Los Sistemas de Control de Versiones (VCS) permiten guardar el rastro de las modificaciones sobre determinados elementos. En el contexto de este proyecto, se gestionarán versiones de archivos y directorios.

Se deberá implementar un sistema de control de versiones simple, que permita:

Adicionar un archivo al repositorio de versiones.
Listar las versiones de un archivo en el repositorio de versiones.
Obtener la versión de un archivo del repositorio de versiones.
En esta implementación sólo se deberá realizar el control de versiones por directorio, en el cual sólo se pueden agregar archivos que se encuentren en el directorio actual (no recursivamente).

**1.1. Repositorio de versiones**

Al invocar el comando ./versions, se deberá crear un sub-directorio llamado .versions, si no existe, en el directorio actual de trabajo. Dentro de este directorio se almacenarán las diferentes versiones del archivo, y un archivo llamado versions.db que contendrá la descripción de cada versión.

**1.2. Adición de archivos al repositorio**
Al invocar el comando:
versions add test.c "Primera version"

Se deberá verificar si la versión actual del archivo es diferente a las anteriores versiones guardadas. Si se cumple esta condición, se creará la nueva versión del archivo en el sub-directorio y se añadirá una línea al archivo

versions.db.

**1.3. Listado de versiones**
El comando:
versions list test.c

Deberá imprimir la información que se encuentra dentro del archivo ver-
sions.db del sub-directorio correspondiente para el archivo.

**1.4. Obtener una versión del archivo**
El comando:
./versions get 1 test.c

Obtendrá la versión solicitada del archivo del repositorio, sobreescribién-
dolo si éste ya existe.

**1.5. Detección de cambios**

El esquema para detección de cambios en un archivo puede ser muy com-
plejo. Para la implementación de este programa, se usará el módulo auxiliar

sha256, el cual implementa el algoritmo del mismo nombre y permite obtener
el código SHA de 256 bits (64 bytes + NULL). (ver función get_file_hash
en el código base proporcionado).

**1.6. Copiar un archivo**

Se deberá implementar una función para copiar el archivo al subdirecto-
rio de versiones. Dado que no existe una llamada al sistema específica para

este propósito, se deberá abrir el archivo original y copiar su contenido al nue-
vo archivo. Esto se puede lograr mediante dos familias de funciones diferentes: open read write close, que operan sobre descriptores de archivo, o

fopen fread fwrite fclose que operan sobre flujos de datos (streams).

**1.7. Llamadas al sistema**
Algunas de las llamadas al sistema y funciones de biblioteca que se pueden
usar para la solución del problema presentado son: fork exec popen exit
open read write close fopen fclose, sha256sum stat. Para gestionar
cadenas de caracteres, se debe reservar memoria dinámica con malloc, copiar
(strcpy), concatenar (strcat), longitud (strlen), comparación (strcmp).

Al ejecutar el comando ***debian@debian:~/Descargas/proyecto_1_vcs_login$*** `versions add README.txt "version 1.0` deberia crear el archivo solicitado en caso de que no exista, de lo contrario si existe una version, osea con la misma clave hash deberia omitirla

**Clase versions.c**

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "sha256.h"
#include "versions.h"
#include <errno.h>


/**
 * @brief Obtiene el hash de un archivo.
 * @param filename Nombre del archivo a obtener el hash
 * @param hash Buffer para almacenar el hash (HASH_SIZE)
 * @return Referencia al buffer, NULL si ocurre error
 */
char *get_file_hash(char *filename, char *hash);

/**
 * @brief Copia un archivo
 *
 * @param source Archivo fuente
 * @param destination Destino
 *
 * @return 1 en caso de exito, 0 si existe error.
 */
int copy(char *source, char *destination);

int add_version(file_version r);

return_code add(char * filename, char * comment) {
    struct stat s;

    // Verificar si el archivo existe
    if (stat(filename, &s) < 0) {
        perror("stat");
        return VERSION_ERROR;
    }

    // Verificar si es un archivo regular
    if (!S_ISREG(s.st_mode)) {
        return VERSION_ERROR;
    }

    // Obtener el hash del archivo
    char *hash = get_file_hash(filename, NULL);
    if (hash == NULL) {
        return VERSION_ERROR;
    }

    // Obtener la longitud de ".versions/" y el hash
    size_t nuevo_len = 0;
    nuevo_len = strlen(".versions/") + strlen(hash) + 1; // +1 para el carácter nulo

    // Asignar memoria para nuevo
    char *nuevo = (char *)malloc(nuevo_len);
    if (nuevo == NULL) {        
        perror("malloc");
        free(nuevo);
        return VERSION_ERROR;
    }

    // Construir la cadena ".versions/hash"
    strcpy(nuevo, ".versions/");
    strcat(nuevo, hash);

    // Copiar el archivo al directorio ".versions"
    if (copy(filename, nuevo) != 1) {
        free(nuevo); // Liberar la memoria asignada a nuevo si hay un error
        return VERSION_ERROR;
    }

    // Crear una estructura de registro_archivo con los datos
    file_version r;
    strncpy(r.filename, filename, sizeof(r.filename));
    strncpy(r.comment, comment, sizeof(r.comment));
    strncpy(r.hash, hash, sizeof(r.hash));

    add_version(r);

    return VERSION_CREATED; // Devuelve VERSION_CREATED si todo se realizó correctamente
}

int add_version(file_version r)
{

    // Abrir el archivo "versions.db" en modo adicionar (append) -> "a"
    FILE *db_file = fopen(VERSIONS_DB_PATH, "a");
    if (db_file == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error al abrir el archivo.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    // Escribe el registro en el archivo "versions.db"
    fprintf(db_file, "%s %s %s\n", r.filename, r.comment, r.hash);

    // Cierra el archivo "versions.db"
    fclose(db_file);

    return 1;
}

void list(char *filename)
{
    // Abrir el archivo ".versions/versions.db"
    FILE *fp = fopen(".versions/versions.db", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("Error al abrir el archivo.\n");
        return;
    }

    int cont = 1;
    file_version r;

    // Leer hasta fin de archivo
    while (!feof(fp)) {
        // Realizar una lectura y validar
        if (fread(&r, sizeof(file_version), 1, fp) != 1) {
            break;
        }

        // Si el registro corresponde al archivo buscado, imprimir
        // Comparación entre cadenas: strcmp
        if (strcmp(r.filename, filename) == 0) {
            printf("%d %s %s\n", cont, r.hash, r.comment);
            cont++;
        }
    }

    if(cont == 1) {
        printf("No hay versiones del archivo %s\n", filename);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}

char *get_file_hash(char *filename, char *hash)
{
    char *comando;
    FILE *fp;

    struct stat s;

    // Verificar que el archivo existe y que se puede obtener el hash
    if (stat(filename, &s) < 0 || !S_ISREG(s.st_mode))
    {
        perror("stat");
        return NULL;
    }

    sha256_hash_file_hex(filename, hash);

    return hash;
}

int copy(char *source, char *destination)
{
    // Abrir el archivo fuente en modo lectura
    int fd_source = open(source, O_RDONLY);
    if (fd_source == -1)
    {
        perror("Error al abrir el archivo fuente");
        return 0;
    }

    // Abrir el archivo destino en modo escritura, creándolo si no existe
    int fd_destination = open(destination, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666);
    if (fd_destination == -1)
    {
        perror("Error al abrir el archivo destino");
        close(fd_source);
        return 0;
    }

    // Buffer para copiar datos
    char buffer[BUFSIZ];
    ssize_t bytes_leidos, bytes_escritos;

    // Copiar datos del archivo fuente al archivo destino
    while ((bytes_leidos = read(fd_source, buffer, BUFSIZ)) > 0)
    {
        bytes_escritos = write(fd_destination, buffer, bytes_leidos);

        if (bytes_escritos == -1)
        {
            perror("Error al escribir en el archivo destino");
            close(fd_source);
            close(fd_destination);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    // Cerrar ambos archivos
    close(fd_source);
    close(fd_destination);

    return 1;
}

return_code get(char *filename, int version)
{
    // Abrir el archivo ".versions/versions.db"
    FILE *fp = fopen(".versions/versions.db", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        return VERSION_DOES_NOT_EXIST;
    }

    int cont = 1;
    file_version r;

    // Leer hasta fin de archivo
    while (!feof(fp)) {
        // Realizar una lectura y validar
        if (fread(&r, sizeof(file_version), 1, fp) != 1) {
            break;
        }

        // Buscar el archivo y la versión solicitada
        if (strcmp(r.filename, filename) == 0) {
            if (cont == version) {
                // Copiar el archivo 
                copy(r.hash, r.filename);

                fclose(fp);
                printf("Version %d del archivo %s obtenida\n", version, filename);
                return VERSION_RETRIEVED;
            } else {
                // Buscar la siguiente versión
                cont++;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);
    printf("No hay versiones del archivo %s\n", filename);
    return VERSION_DOES_NOT_EXIST;
}
```

**Clase versions.h**

```
#ifndef VERSIONS_H
#define VERSIONS_H

#include <dirent.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "sha256.h"

#define COMMENT_SIZE BUFSIZ /** < Longitud del comentario */
#define HASH_SIZE 65 /**< Longitud del hash incluyendo NULL*/

#define VERSIONS_DB "versions.db" /**< Nombre de la base de datos de versiones. */
#define VERSIONS_DIR ".versions" /**< Directorio del repositorio. */
#define VERSIONS_DB_PATH VERSIONS_DIR "/" VERSIONS_DB /**< Ruta completa de la base de datos.*/


#define EQUALS(s1, s2) (strcmp(s1, s2) == 0) /**< Verdadero si dos cadenas son iguales.*/

/**
 * @brief Version de un archivo.
 * Para cada version de un archivo se almacena el nombre original,
 * el comentario del usuario y el hash de su contenido.
 * El hash es a la vez el nombre del archivo dentro del 
 * repositorio.
 */
typedef struct {
    char filename[NAME_MAX]; /**< Nombre del archivo original. */
    char hash[HASH_SIZE];           /**< Hash del contenido del archivo. */
    char comment[COMMENT_SIZE];    /**< Comentario del usuario. */
}file_version;


typedef enum {
    VERSION_ERROR,
    VERSION_CREATED,
    VERSION_ADDED,
    VERSION_ALREADY_EXISTS,
    VERSION_DOES_NOT_EXIST,
    VERSION_RETRIEVED
}return_code;


/**
 * @brief Adiciona un archivo al repositorio.
 *
 * @param filename Nombre del archivo a adicionar
 * @param comment Comentario de la version actual
 *
 * @return Codigo de la operacion
 */
return_code add(char * filename, char * comment);

/**
 * @brief Lista las versiones de un archivo.
 *
 * @param filename Nombre del archivo, NULL para listar todo el repositorio.
 */
void list(char * filename);

/**
 * @brief Obtiene una version del un archivo.
 * Sobreescribe la version existente.
 *
 * @param filename Nombre de archivo.
 * @param version Numero secuencial de la version.
 *
 * @return Codigo de la operacion (VERSION_ERROR,VERSION_DOES_NOT_EXIST, VERSIO_RETRIEVED)
 */
return_code get(char * filename, int version);

#endif
```

**Clase sha256.c**

```
/*
     MIT License

     Copyright (c) 2020 LekKit https://github.com/LekKit

     Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
     of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
     in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
     to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
     copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
     furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

     The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
     copies or substantial portions of the Software.

     THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
     IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
     FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
     AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
     LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
     OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
     SOFTWARE.
 */

/* Details of the implementation, etc can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2
     See sha256.h for short documentation on library usage */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "sha256.h"

void sha256_init(struct sha256_buff* buff) {
    buff->h[0] = 0x6a09e667;
    buff->h[1] = 0xbb67ae85;
    buff->h[2] = 0x3c6ef372;
    buff->h[3] = 0xa54ff53a;
    buff->h[4] = 0x510e527f;
    buff->h[5] = 0x9b05688c;
    buff->h[6] = 0x1f83d9ab;
    buff->h[7] = 0x5be0cd19;
    buff->data_size = 0;
    buff->chunk_size = 0;
}

const static uint32_t k[64] = {
    0x428a2f98, 0x71374491, 0xb5c0fbcf, 0xe9b5dba5, 0x3956c25b, 0x59f111f1, 0x923f82a4, 0xab1c5ed5,
    0xd807aa98, 0x12835b01, 0x243185be, 0x550c7dc3, 0x72be5d74, 0x80deb1fe, 0x9bdc06a7, 0xc19bf174,
    0xe49b69c1, 0xefbe4786, 0x0fc19dc6, 0x240ca1cc, 0x2de92c6f, 0x4a7484aa, 0x5cb0a9dc, 0x76f988da,
    0x983e5152, 0xa831c66d, 0xb00327c8, 0xbf597fc7, 0xc6e00bf3, 0xd5a79147, 0x06ca6351, 0x14292967,
    0x27b70a85, 0x2e1b2138, 0x4d2c6dfc, 0x53380d13, 0x650a7354, 0x766a0abb, 0x81c2c92e, 0x92722c85,
    0xa2bfe8a1, 0xa81a664b, 0xc24b8b70, 0xc76c51a3, 0xd192e819, 0xd6990624, 0xf40e3585, 0x106aa070,
    0x19a4c116, 0x1e376c08, 0x2748774c, 0x34b0bcb5, 0x391c0cb3, 0x4ed8aa4a, 0x5b9cca4f, 0x682e6ff3,
    0x748f82ee, 0x78a5636f, 0x84c87814, 0x8cc70208, 0x90befffa, 0xa4506ceb, 0xbef9a3f7, 0xc67178f2
};

#define rotate_r(val, bits) (val >> bits | val << (32 - bits))

static void sha256_calc_chunk(struct sha256_buff* buff, const uint8_t* chunk) {
    uint32_t w[64];
    uint32_t tv[8];
    uint32_t i;

    for (i=0; i<16; ++i){
        w[i] = (uint32_t) chunk[0] << 24 | (uint32_t) chunk[1] << 16 | (uint32_t) chunk[2] << 8 | (uint32_t) chunk[3];
        chunk += 4;
    }

    for (i=16; i<64; ++i){
        uint32_t s0 = rotate_r(w[i-15], 7) ^ rotate_r(w[i-15], 18) ^ (w[i-15] >> 3);
        uint32_t s1 = rotate_r(w[i-2], 17) ^ rotate_r(w[i-2], 19) ^ (w[i-2] >> 10);
        w[i] = w[i-16] + s0 + w[i-7] + s1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        tv[i] = buff->h[i];

    for (i=0; i<64; ++i){
        uint32_t S1 = rotate_r(tv[4], 6) ^ rotate_r(tv[4], 11) ^ rotate_r(tv[4], 25);
        uint32_t ch = (tv[4] & tv[5]) ^ (~tv[4] & tv[6]);
        uint32_t temp1 = tv[7] + S1 + ch + k[i] + w[i];
        uint32_t S0 = rotate_r(tv[0], 2) ^ rotate_r(tv[0], 13) ^ rotate_r(tv[0], 22);
        uint32_t maj = (tv[0] & tv[1]) ^ (tv[0] & tv[2]) ^ (tv[1] & tv[2]);
        uint32_t temp2 = S0 + maj;

        tv[7] = tv[6];
        tv[6] = tv[5];
        tv[5] = tv[4];
        tv[4] = tv[3] + temp1;
        tv[3] = tv[2];
        tv[2] = tv[1];
        tv[1] = tv[0];
        tv[0] = temp1 + temp2;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        buff->h[i] += tv[i];
}

void sha256_update(struct sha256_buff* buff, const void* data, size_t size) {
    const uint8_t* ptr = (const uint8_t*)data;
    buff->data_size += size;
    /* If there is data left in buff, concatenate it to process as new chunk */
    if (size + buff->chunk_size >= 64) {
        uint8_t tmp_chunk[64];
        memcpy(tmp_chunk, buff->last_chunk, buff->chunk_size);
        memcpy(tmp_chunk + buff->chunk_size, ptr, 64 - buff->chunk_size);
        ptr += (64 - buff->chunk_size);
        size -= (64 - buff->chunk_size);
        buff->chunk_size = 0;
        sha256_calc_chunk(buff, tmp_chunk);
    }
    /* Run over data chunks */
    while (size  >= 64) {
        sha256_calc_chunk(buff, ptr);
        ptr += 64;
        size -= 64; 
    }

    /* Save remaining data in buff, will be reused on next call or finalize */
    memcpy(buff->last_chunk + buff->chunk_size, ptr, size);
    buff->chunk_size += size;
}

void sha256_finalize(struct sha256_buff* buff) {
    buff->last_chunk[buff->chunk_size] = 0x80;
    buff->chunk_size++;
    memset(buff->last_chunk + buff->chunk_size, 0, 64 - buff->chunk_size);

    /* If there isn't enough space to fit int64, pad chunk with zeroes and prepare next chunk */
    if (buff->chunk_size > 56) {
        sha256_calc_chunk(buff, buff->last_chunk);
        memset(buff->last_chunk, 0, 64);
    }

    /* Add total size as big-endian int64 x8 */
    uint64_t size = buff->data_size * 8;
    int i;
    for (i = 8; i > 0; --i) {
        buff->last_chunk[55+i] = size & 255;
        size >>= 8;
    }

    sha256_calc_chunk(buff, buff->last_chunk);
}

void sha256_read(const struct sha256_buff* buff, uint8_t* hash) {
    uint32_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        hash[i*4] = (buff->h[i] >> 24) & 255;
        hash[i*4 + 1] = (buff->h[i] >> 16) & 255;
        hash[i*4 + 2] = (buff->h[i] >> 8) & 255;
        hash[i*4 + 3] = buff->h[i] & 255;
    }
}

static void bin_to_hex(const void* data, uint32_t len, char* out) {
    static const char* const lut = "0123456789abcdef";
    uint32_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i){
        uint8_t c = ((uint8_t*)data)[i];
        out[i*2] = lut[c >> 4];
        out[i*2 + 1] = lut[c & 15];
    }
}

void sha256_read_hex(const struct sha256_buff* buff, char* hex) {
    uint8_t hash[32];
    sha256_read(buff, hash);
    bin_to_hex(hash, 32, hex);
}

void sha256_hash(const void* data, size_t size, uint8_t* hash) {
    struct sha256_buff buff;
    sha256_init(&buff);
    sha256_update(&buff, data, size);
    sha256_finalize(&buff);
    sha256_read(&buff, hash);
}

void sha256_hash_hex(const void* data, size_t size, char* hex) {
    uint8_t hash[32];
    sha256_hash(data, size, hash);
    bin_to_hex(hash, 32, hex);
}

void sha256_hash_file_hex(char * path, char * hex) {
    FILE* file = fopen(path, "rb");
    if (!file){
        return;
    }
    char buffer[1024];
    size_t size;
    struct sha256_buff buff;
    sha256_init(&buff);
    while (!feof(file)){
        /* Hash file by 1kb chunks, instead of loading into RAM at once */
        size = fread(buffer, 1, 1024, file);
        sha256_update(&buff, buffer, size);
    }
    char hash[65] = {0}; /* hash[64] is null-byte */
    sha256_finalize(&buff);

    hex[64] = 0;
    sha256_read_hex(&buff, hex);
}
```

**clase sha256.h**

```
/*
    MIT License

    Copyright (c) 2020 LekKit https://github.com/LekKit

    Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
    of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
    in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
    to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
    copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
    furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

    The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all
    copies or substantial portions of the Software.

    THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
    IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
    FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
    AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
    LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
    OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN THE
    SOFTWARE.
*/

#ifndef SHA256_H
#define SHA256_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>

struct sha256_buff {
    uint64_t data_size;
    uint32_t h[8];
    uint8_t last_chunk[64];
    uint8_t chunk_size;
};

/* Initialization, must be called before any further use */
void sha256_init(struct sha256_buff* buff);

/* Process block of data of arbitary length, can be used on data streams (files, etc) */
void sha256_update(struct sha256_buff* buff, const void* data, size_t size);

/* Produces final hash values (digest) to be read
   If the buffer is reused later, init must be called again */
void sha256_finalize(struct sha256_buff* buff);

/* Read digest into 32-byte binary array */
void sha256_read(const struct sha256_buff* buff, uint8_t* hash);

/* Read digest into 64-char string as hex (without null-byte) */
void sha256_read_hex(const struct sha256_buff* buff, char* hex);

/* Hashes single contiguous block of data and reads digest into 32-byte binary array */
void sha256_hash(const void* data, size_t size, uint8_t* hash);

/* Hashes single contiguous block of data and reads digest into 64-char string (without null-byte) */
void sha256_hash_hex(const void* data, size_t size, char* hex);

/* Hashes a file */
void sha256_hash_file_hex(char * path, char * hex);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}

#include <string>

class SHA256 {
private:
    struct sha256_buff buff;
public:
    SHA256() {
        sha256_init(&buff);
    }
    
    void update(const void* data, std::size_t size) {
        sha256_update(&buff, data, size);
    }
    
    std::string hash() {
        char hash[64];
        sha256_finalize(&buff);
        sha256_read_hex(&buff, hash);
        sha256_init(&buff);
        return std::string(hash, 64);
    }
    
    static std::string hashString(const std::string& str) {
        char hash[64];
        sha256_hash_hex(str.c_str(), str.length(), hash);
        return std::string(hash, 64);
    }
};

#endif

#endif
```

**Clase main.c**

```
/*
 * @file
 * @author Erwin Meza Vega <emezav@gmail.com>
 * Sistema de Control de Versiones
 * Uso: 
 *      versions add ARCHIVO "Comentario" : Adiciona una version del archivo al repositorio
 *      versions list ARCHIVO             : Lista las versiones del archivo existentes
 *      versions get numver ARCHIVO       : Obtiene una version del archivo del repositorio
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "versions.h"

/**
* @brief Imprime la ayuda
*/
void print_help();

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct stat s;

    mkdir(VERSIONS_DIR, 0755);

    if (stat(VERSIONS_DB_PATH, &s) != 0) {
        creat(VERSIONS_DB_PATH, 0755);
    }

    if (argc == 4
            && EQUALS(argv[1], "add")) {
        if (add(argv[2], argv[3]) == VERSION_ERROR) {
            fprintf(stderr, "No se puede adicionar %s\n", argv[2]);
        }
    }else if (argc == 2
            && EQUALS(argv[1], "list")) {
        //Listar todos los archivos almacenados en el repositorio
        list(NULL);
    }else if (argc == 3
            && EQUALS(argv[1], "list")) {
        //Listar el archivo solicitado
        list(argv[2]);
    }else if (argc == 4
            && EQUALS(argv[1], "get")) {
        int version = atoi(argv[2]);
        if (version <= 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Numero de version invalido\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        if (!get(argv[3], version)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "No se puede obtener la version %d de %s\n", version, argv[3]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }else {
        print_help();
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

}

void print_help() {
    printf("Uso: \n");
    printf("versions add ARCHIVO \"Comentario\" : Adiciona una version del archivo al repositorio\n");
    printf("versions list ARCHIVO             : Lista las versiones del archivo existentes\n");
    printf("versions get numver ARCHIVO       : Obtiene una version del archivo del repositorio\n");
}
```

**Makefile**

```
all: main.o sha256.o versions.o
    gcc -o versions main.o sha256.o versions.o

main.o: main.c
    gcc -c -o main.o main.c

sha256.o: sha256.c
    gcc -c -o sha256.o sha256.c

versions.o: versions.c
    gcc -c -o versions.o versions.c

clean: 
    rm -f versions *.o
    rm -rf docs

clean-repo:
    rm -rf .versions

doc:
    doxygen

install: all
    sudo cp versions /usr/local/bin

uninstall:
    sudo rm -f /usr/local/bin/versions
```

Comment: Podrías incluir el stacktrace en el momento que ocurre el error? Tienes que agregar el parámetro `-g` al compilador y depurar el código, con `gdb` o el que prefieras.

Comment: Por favor muestra cómo estás ejecutando el programa en lugar de un enunciado.

Comment: Y especifica claramente donde esta el problema.. pusiste tu programa completo, pero nos va a costar encontrar tu problema si no enfocas mas la pregunta...

Comment: Pasas `NULL` cuando llamas `sha256_hash_file_hex`. Por eso obtienes segfault.